# Series with poles of Gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

So I have a series:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\Gamma(-n)}$.

Can I just argue that $\lim_{n\to k} \frac{x^n}{\Gamma(-n)}$, $\forall k \in N_0$ is zero and thus the whole series becomes a null series?

Or do I have to justify it more?
And in what way can I improve my argument?

Comment: In what sense do you "have that series"? What does $\Gamma(-n)$ even mean, given that the gamma function is undefined at the non-positive integers?

Comment: I agree the series is actually not a series due to the series having undefined terms.

That was my first confusion too when I read this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08942.pdf

At the end of page 2, 1.6

Comment: Yeah, I think in that case it’s clear that they are taking $1/\Gamma(-n)=0$. If you prefer, we can just think $1/\Gamma(z)$ suitably extended to be an entire function .

Comment: So my above-mentioned should be a good enough explanation for how $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-n)}=0$?

I am not sure if I have properly understood about extending $\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}$ to be an entire function.

I read about meromorphic functions and how the Gamma function is one of such functions.
So I had a small follow up question:

From wikipedia I found:

A zero of a meromorphic function $f$ is a complex number $z$ such that $f(z) = 0$. A pole of $f$ is a zero of $\frac{1}{f}$.

So can I just say a pole of $\Gamma$ is a zero of $\frac{1}{\Gamma}$

Comment: I have no background in complex analysis. Just learned about this meromorphic function from the wiki.
Apologies if it doesn't sound coherent.

Comment: Yes, that is the right idea... the poles become zeros and vice versa. (And then since $\Gamma$ has no zeros, and no singularities other than poles, $1/\Gamma$ is entire.)